# Bootstrap button markup echo checked

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

When trying to get the bootstrap radio button checked I am comparing 2 variables. I am absolutely 100% sure the are equal but the button is not marked as checked.
What might be the issue here?

```
echo '<label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" value="'.$value.'" '; 
if($row_list['bedrijf'] == $value) { 
    echo 'checked '; 
}
echo 'autocomplete="off" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()"><img src="images/logo_'.$value.'_small.png" height="30"></label>';
```

HTML output

```
<div class="form-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" value="mb" autocomplete="off" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()"><img src="images/logo_mb_small.png" height="30"></label><label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" value="thure" checked autocomplete="off" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()"><img src="images/logo_thure_small.png" height="30"></label><label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" value="torza" autocomplete="off" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()"><img src="images/logo_torza_small.png" height="30"></label></div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like when you view the html source?

Comment: You need space around `checked`

Comment: Tried unique ids? Also, I think `autocomplete` is unavailable for `<input type="radio">.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space in front of the `autocomplete` keyword. Currently, it renders as `... checkedautocomplete="off" onclick="...`.

You can also inline the if statement as follows:

```
echo '<label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" value="'.$value.'" '.($row_list['bedrijf'] == $value ? 'checked' : '').' autocomplete="off" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()">

    <img src="images/logo_'.$value.'_small.png" height="30">
</label>';
```

Comment: I just tested this, see my edits but still the same result.

Comment: In your edit, the second input has the `checked` attribute. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: Yes I do but the button itself is not shown as checked.